# Plesk Mailserver - Multiply accounts for one email

Tags: email, plesk, email-validation, debian-stretch

Good evening to all,

I currently use Plesk Obsidian 18 | Hoster edition (deb 9) and with it also the intigrated mail server.

Well, it's all very good that I can now create emails, so also send and receive.

But for some personal applications I would like to have multiple accounts for only one email address.

e.g. I have the email address "no-reply@example.com".
Then I don't want to be authenticated with

```
"no-reply@example.com:my password"
```

but e.g. with

```
"service1.no-reply@exampe.com:my password"
"service2.no-reply@exampe.com:my password"
"service3.no-reply@exampe.com:my password"
```

log in.
But still be able to send and receive e-mails via the e-mail address "no-reply@example.com". (Whereby the receiving is irrelevant here for now. At least for me).

I have already looked around in Plesk doc, but found nothing where I could have created multiple accounts.

It would also be very nice if this is ultimately doable via the panel and not have to set in any config files. But even that works in a pinch.

I have full access to the server and can therefore also adjust Plesk configdatein.

I hope I have explained this well.